# how to compare two pipe delimited text files, find out the difference and copy the output to third file using linux script

Tags: linux, awk, diff

I want to compare two pipe delimited text files and find out the difference between two files using Linux script and write/copy the difference to output file.

scenario 1

File 1

```
5756366|99|HOLDER, CTLY 6X12X15.5 PLST|HOLDER, CUTLERY 6X12X15.5 PLASTIC COPPER FINISH W/|INSERT|A
1516020|99|CHEESE, CRM GRDN VEG SPRED|CHEESE, CREAM GARDEN VEGETABLE SPREAD PLASTIC TUB|REF|A
5086368|99|MAT, CRPT 4'X6' OLEFN CHRCL|MAT, CARPET 4'X6' OLEFIN CHARCOAL CATALINA||A
```

File 2

```
5756366|99|HOLDER, CTLY 6X12X15.5 PLST|HOLDER, CUTLERY 6X12X15.5 PLASTIC COPPER FINISH W/|INSERT|A
1516020|99|CHEESE, CRM GRDN VEG SPRED|CHEESE, CREAM GARDEN VEGETABLE SPREAD PLASTIC TUB|REF|A
5086368|99|MAT, CRPT 4'X6' OLEFN CHRCL|MAT, CARPET 4'X6' OLEFIN CHARCOAL CATALINA||A
5639166|99|COVER, DOME TRAY 12X20 PCRBN|COVER, CLEAR SIDE CU|T OUT W/ HINGED DOOR LID|A
```

Here, I want to get the difference between two files. In this case, the file 2 is having extra record 5639166|99|COVER, DOME TRAY 12X20 PCRBN|COVER, CLEAR SIDE CU|T OUT W/ HINGED DOOR LID|A and this should be saved to a Diff File as shown below

Diff File

```
5639166|99|COVER, DOME TRAY 12X20 PCRBN|COVER, CLEAR SIDE CU|T OUT W/ HINGED DOOR LID|A
```

Scenario 2

File 1

```
5756366|99|HOLDER, CTLY 6X12X15.5 PLST|HOLDER, CUTLERY 6X12X15.5 PLASTIC COPPER FINISH W/|INSERT|A 1516020|99|CHEESE, CRM GRDN VEG SPRED|CHEESE, CREAM GARDEN VEGETABLE SPREAD PLASTIC TUB|REF|A
```

File 2

```
5756366|99|HOLDER, CTLY 6X12X15.5 PLST|HOLDER, CUTLERY 6X12X15.5 PLASTIC COPPER FINISH W/|INSERT|A 1516020|99|CHEESE, CRM GRDN VEG SPRED TEST|CHEESE, CREAM GARDEN VEGETABLE SPREAD PLASTIC TUB|REF|I
```

Here in this scenario, there is a change in the data for 1516020 record,So in the diff File i should have only 1516020 record as below

Diff File

```
1516020|99|CHEESE, CRM GRDN VEG SPRED TEST|CHEESE, CREAM GARDEN VEGETABLE SPREAD PLASTIC TUB|REF|I
```

Would any one please help me out with Linux script for the above scenarios.

Comment: So why can't you just look at the output of `diff` again?

Comment: (1) If you were dealing with files that said ``17 cheese`` and ``42 mouse``, would you be able to do this yourself?  If yes, tell us how you would do it.  If not, why are you asking a question with an arbitrary extra complication?  Ask one question at a time, and do research first.  (2) If you were dealing with files that consisted of lines with under 200 characters, would that make the problem easier?  If not, use example data that people can look at and read, like ``17|cheese`` and ``42|mouse``, rather than 200-character long lines full of capital letters.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: I guess that, when the user says “Diff File”, they mean “this is the output I want”, and not that they even know about the `diff` command.

Comment: Type `man diff` and `man comm` on your computer, try something and then come back with a question if you need help with whatever it is you tried.

Answer (score 1):

For scenario1 Below command will work, Tested and worked fine

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print $0}'  file1 file2 > diff
```

output

```
5639166|99|COVER, DOME TRAY 12X20 PCRBN|COVER, CLEAR SIDE CU|T OUT W/ HINGED DOOR LID|A
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, That was a great help.